# Why is my header not in the center?

Tags: css, html, header, alignment

Here's a link: 
http://www.cultsectsclothing.com/shop

Can someone please help me? I can't figure out why the header won't center. Instead, it's awkwardly all the way to the right. I feel like it's something really simple but I don't even know...

I have already tried redoing the header on css and in the html cascade layout. It's the same way I do the header on all the other pages. I just need the stupid title to center and for some odd reason it is not.

I checked my  tags and made sure they matched up with my 's too. Help??

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cultsectsclothing.com%2Fshop&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: `position: fixed;` and `left: 0;` this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Give CSS Like this for `#header` and it will Work No Doubt !

```
#header {
font-size: 60px;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
position: fixed;
top: 30px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2QsHz/4/)

Add `margin: 0 auto;` in your `#header`. This will solve your problem..

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"><a href="/">CULT SECTS</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header { 
   font-size: 60px;
   font-style:oblique;
   font-weight:bold;
   color: #000;  
   text-align: center;
   margin 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 30px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for your header:

```
#header { 
  width:980px;
  height:130px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
width: 1000px;
```

Put

```
width: 100%;
```

on the #header CSS style.
It will look like this: http://d.pr/i/2OKD
And the fixed will be still there, so, your "logo" will not scroll (like the menu).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#header {
font-size: 60px;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
position: fixed;
top: 30px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In context to your code, you simply need to add two properties to your #header rule, which are left: 0 and width: 100% (remove your 1000px as I'm assuming you just want the header to be centered and don't care about an exact width)

See the last 2 properties in the code block below:

```
#header {
font-size: 60px;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
position: fixed;
top: 30px;
min-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/uberrobert/F4TgR/

This will make your header come back from the right as I see that behavior in Firefox :)